# Cannot convert dynamic object into string collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am trying to convert a dynamic datatype into a string collection but The program crashes when getting to the last line of the first block and I simply can't find any good method to solve it.

```
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);   
var firstInArray = result[0];

string UserId = firstInArray.userId.Value;
int OrderNumber = Convert.ToInt32(firstInArray.orderNumber.Value);

string[] CustomerId = firstInArray.customerId.Values;
```

The data:

```
[
{
    "userId": "H554S",
    "orderNumber": 0,
    "customerId": [
        "J800",
        "J801",
        "J802"
    ]

},
{
"userId": 
...
...
}
```

Comment: When you put in a breakpoint on `var firstInArray = result[0];` and typed `result` into the watch window in the debugger, what did you see?

Comment: What is the real benefit to use dynamic type instead of a declared class with the needed properties?

Comment: {{  "userId": "H554S" ,  "orderNumber": 0,  "customerId": [    "J800",    "J801",    "J802"  ]  }} @EdPlunkett

Comment: OK, now you know what's there, so you can find what you want.

Comment: That's not what I see when I parse the JSON you showed in your question, but I wasn't all that confident it would be. Or were you looking at `result[0]` instead?

Comment: @SirRufo I'm seeking to store the values in a class consisting those variables:

     public string UserId { get; set; }
     public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
     public string[] CustomerId { get; set; }

Comment: Then declare that class and use it for deserialization.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I only included result[0]

Comment: @SirRufo Still getting the same error, method breaks and no data left in the class

Comment: @David `result[0].customerId` is of type `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray`, which is probably documented. Anyway you can index it, and it has a `Count` property. You can call ToList() or ToArray() on it.

Comment: @David Did you try JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<YourClass>>( json ) ? Your json is an array of objects and therefore you need a collection to deserialize to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not getting any errors, take a look at this small sample:

```
var obj = new []
{
    new {
        userId = "User1",
        orderNUmber = 0,
        customerId = new [] { "Foo", "Bar", "Woot" }
    },
    new {
        userId = "User2",
        orderNUmber = 0,
        customerId = new [] { "Foo", "Bar", "Woot" }
    },
};

var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

string UserId = result[0].userId.Value;
```

It works fine for me.

> **Given your error, the problem is most likely your json is malformed.**

*The above `obj` is the equivalent to this json:*

```
[
  {
    "userId": "User1",
    "orderNUmber": 0,
    "customerId": [ "Foo", "Bar", "Woot" ]
  },
  {
    "userId": "User2",
    "orderNUmber": 0,
    "customerId": [ "Foo", "Bar", "Woot" ]
  }
]
```

---

### Alternative (and better in almost all cases than to use `dynamic`)

Instead of using a `dynamic` type, just map it to the the model. To do that, change it to:

```
var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bar>(json);
```

and make these classes (examples)

```
public class Bar : List<Foo>
{
}

public class Foo
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public List<string> CustomerId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work with my solution, all variables dissapear from the Autos window and the method breaks

Comment: I've tried to map it directly. Is it possible to change from List<string> to string[] ?

Comment: I would stick to using `List<string>` instead of `string[]`. Is this answer working for you?

Answer (score 0):

You should really take Sir Rufo and Svek's advice about deserializing a strongly typed class. Newtonsoft JSON is very friendly with that type of thing; you can use [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com) to generate the class from a JSON sample.

But you can figure things out just by inspecting the object in the debugger and finding out exactly what you've got. Time spent guessing is wasted, 100% wasted, every single time. You'd accomplish as much in front of the TV or taking drugs.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

foreach (var r in result)
{
    Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray ids = result[0].customerId;

    var idlist = ids.ToList();

    //  This throws an exception. Go figure.
    var idlist2 = result[0].customerId.ToList();
}
```